# What is the error type when PostgreSQL exhausts a sequence?

Tags: postgresql

I want to generate primary keys within my database using a PostgreSQL sequence. Rather than having one big sequence, it's broken up into little chunks (key series) though (this has to do with clients working offline and syncing their work later).

I have written a table that holds the next key series to be issued and a function that will issue a new series and update the key sequence. I'm now making a trigger to attach primary keys to inserted rows if none is already set.

**How can I catch when the key sequence is exhausted?** What exception do I need to catch? I want to do something like this:

```
create or replace function generate_key() returns trigger as
$$
begin
    if new._id is null then
       begin
           new._id = nextval(key_sequence);
       exception when SEQUENCE_EXHAUSTED then
           perform update_key_sequence();
           new._id = nextval(key_sequence);
       end; 
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

I've googled unsuccessfully and tried it out on a mini sequence, but all that did was give an unspecific "Error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty easy to test this out by starting a sequence at the maximum value of a 64-bit signed integer:

```
regress=> CREATE SEQUENCE xx START WITH 9223372036854775807;
CREATE SEQUENCE
regress=> \set verbosity verbose
regress=> SELECT nextval('xx');
       nextval       
---------------------
 9223372036854775807
(1 row)
regress=> SELECT nextval('xx');
ERROR:  55000: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "xx" (9223372036854775807)
LOCATION:  nextval_internal, sequence.c:644
```

so, `SQLSTATE` 55000, [which is `object_not_in_prerequisite_state`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html). Perhaps not the most useful error in the world.

The same error is raised with an explicit `MAXVALUE` for the sequence, again easily tested.

Comment: Thanks, that works beautifully. Odd though, even when I do `\set verbosity verbose` psql still doesn't show me the sqlstate o.O

Comment: Case sensitive. `VERBOSITY`. Not convinced it's meant to be.

Comment: Not any more, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839634/what-is-the-error-type-when-postgresql-exhausts-a-sequence/64571473#64571473

Answer (score 2):

I would say sqlstate 55000 `object_not_in_prerequisite_state`

Tried on 9.2:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "seq_try_max_100"
    INCREMENT BY 10
    MAXVALUE 100
    START WITH 99 NO CYCLE;

SELECT nextval('seq_try_max_100');
SELECT nextval('seq_try_max_100');

-- shows:

ERROR: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "seq_try_max_100" (100)
SQL state: 55000
```

---

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "seq_try_no_max"
    INCREMENT BY 5000000000000000000
    START WITH 5000000000000000000 NO CYCLE;

SELECT nextval('seq_try_no_max');
SELECT nextval('seq_try_no_max');

-- shows:

ERROR: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "seq_try_no_max" (9223372036854775807)
SQL state: 55000
```

Comment: Not any more, see my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839634/what-is-the-error-type-when-postgresql-exhausts-a-sequence/64571473#64571473

Answer (score 2):

[Since Postgres 10](https://www.mail-archive.com/pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org/msg307447.html), the error code in this scenario has been changed to the more informative `2200H`: `sequence_generator_limit_exceeded`.

```
mydb=> \set VERBOSITY verbose
mydb=> INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('x');
ERROR:  2200H: nextval: reached maximum value of sequence "test_id_seq" (4)
LOCATION:  nextval_internal, sequence.c:707
```